# How do I group together lines from a file?

Tags: python

I stored object descriptions in a file, with a newline `\n` to separate all of them. When I open the file, it looks allright, but I cannot take the lines out like I put them into the file. The problem is where a description has more than one line, and the code to separate the different descriptions does not work. Does anybody know a (simple) way to solve this?

I want put each description in its own variable, to connect it with the title later.

```
def test(self):
    #each object has its own title and description, so with the length of the title list,
    #the same amount of descriptions can be put together
    with open(self.title_file, 'r') as f:
        self.title_list = []
        for line in f:
            self.title_list.append(str(line))    
            
    with open(self.description_file, 'r') as f:
        self.description_list = []
        for line in f:
            self.description_list.append(line)

    self.test_list = []

    for i in range(len(self.title_list)):
        self.test_list.append('')
        for line in self.description_tlist:
            if line != '\n':    #I wanted to test whether an item is only a \n, 
                                #which means
                                #end of the description in a file
                self.test_list[i] += line
            if line == '\n':
                break #break, pass or continue?
                
    print(self.description_list)
```

the file contents:

```
Newton sat under a tree when 
an apple landed on his head,
and he discovered gravity.

Einstein wrote some impressive
work with his thought experiments about light.

Eratosthenes was one of the 
first to calculate the circum-
ference of the earth.
```

current output:

```
['Newton sat under a tree when \nan apple landed on his head,\nand he discovered gravity.\n', 'Newton sat under a tree when \nan apple landed on his head,\nand he discovered gravity.\n', 
'Newton sat under a tree when \nan apple landed on his head,\nand he discovered gravity.\n', 'Newton sat under a tree when \nan apple landed on his head,\nand he discovered gravity.\n', 
'Newton sat under a tree when \nan apple landed on his head,\nand he discovered gravity.\n', 'Newton sat under a tree when \nan apple landed on his head,\nand he discovered gravity.\n']
```

Expected output:

`['Newton sat under a tree when an apple landed on his head, and he discovered gravity.', 'Einstein wrote some impressive work with his thought experiments about light.', 'Eratosthenes was one of the first to calculate the circumference of the earth.']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the easiest way I can think of doing this is reading the whole file and splitting on empty lines:

```py
paragraphs = file.read().split("\n\n")
```

If you then want to make the phrases continues with no new-lines, just do:

```py
phrases = [paragraph.replace("\n", " ") for paragraph in file.read().split("\n\n")]
```

Which gives:

```
['Newton sat under a tree when  an apple landed on his head, and he discovered gravity.', 
 'Einstein wrote some impressive work with his thought experiments about light.', 
 'Eratosthenes was one of the  first to calculate the circum- ference of the earth.']
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems trivial-

```py
import re

with open('data.txt', 'r') as datafile:
    data = datafile.read()
data = re.sub(r'(?<=[^\n])\n(?=[^\n])', ' ', data).split('\n\n')

print(data)
```

This essentially just reads the entire text file, replaces all the single new lines with one space (or whatever you want) and then splits the result by double new lines. Essentially dividing the text into "paragraphs" and getting rid of the newlines.

There are also other similar ways, you can split by double new lines first and then parse each group the way you want etc.

Output-

```
 ['Newton sat under a tree when an apple landed on his head, and he discovered gravity.', 'Einstein wrote some impressive work with his thought experiments about light.', 'Eratosthenes was one of the first to calculate the circum- ference of the earth.']
```